# Auto ecryptfs mounting only works after cloning

Tags: ecryptfs, clonezilla

Weird problem, I have an auto ecryptfs setup on a machine. I have an init.d script which is setup to automount the ecryptfs. It was working at one point, and even now if I run the script directly it mounts. However, it no longer works automatically now.

The weird part is, if I clone the system using Clonezilla, the cloned machine works OK and gets automounted.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?